# hadoop connection refused on port 8020

Tags: linux, hadoop, service, hive

Hadoop, hive, hdfs, spark were running fine on my namenode and were able to connect to datanode as well. But for some reason, the server was shutdown and now when I try to access hadoop filesystem via commands  like **hadoop fs -ls /** or if I try to access **hive**, connection is refused on port 8020.

I can see that cloudera-scm-server and cloudera-scm-agent services are running fine. I tried to check the status of hiveserver2, hivemetastore, hadoop-hdfs etc. services, but the **service  status** command gives an errors message that these services do not exist.
Also, I tried to look for start-all.sh but could not find it. I ran **find / -name start-all.sh** command and only the path for start-all.sh in the cloudera parcel directory for spark came up.

I checked the logs in /var/log directory, for hiveserver2 it is pretty clear that the service was shutdown .. other logs are not that clear but I am guessing all the services went down when the server powered off.

Please advise on how to bring up the whole system again. I am unable to access cloudera manager or ambari or anything on the webpages either. Those pages are down too and I am not sure if I even have access to those because I've never tried it before, I've only been working on the linux command line.

Comment: If you see the logs that services are shutdown, can you check how did they get shutdown, it usually shows the error that caused the shutdown.

Comment: In my opinion, if you have a Cloudera Cluster and aren't using Cloudera Manager, I don't see a reason why Cloudera was picked over any other Hadoop installation

Comment: @VikiG - I have checked the logs. They simply show shutting down messages. A few show SIGTERM 15 received. I guess that's signal to terminate. Where else can I check? I restarted cdh-scm-server and cdh-scm-agent services.  My understanding was restarting these services would restart the cluster but there was no effect. These services are running but hive, hdfs, hadoop, datanode etc. are not working.

Comment: @cricket_007 - I am not able to access the cloudera manager webpage. I guess the port 7180 is not up and running.

Comment: Well, if you can't find start-dfs at least, even using `sudo find /`, then I'm not sure how you'd get at least hdfs back up

Comment: @cricket_007 - by any chance, is it possible that start-dfs etc. do not exist on the system? Is it possible that the cluster was running fine earlier in spite of these services missing from the system? If that is not the case, then I can only think that somehow all these files got deleted somehow and a re-installation is required. Is there any other way to fix this without re-installing?

Comment: Those scripts are part of the Apache Hadoop project. I have not used a Cloudera Cluster in a few years, but I would like to think those scripts should exist somewhere. Or see https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-11-x/topics/cdh_ig_hdfs_cluster_deploy.html#concept_ddw_3v1_5l

Comment: If these scripts are part of Hadoop then do all the hive/hdfs etc. services get kicked when we restart the cdh-scm-server and cdh-scm-agent services?